# Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax when changing lambda function to python from js

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I create a lambda function with runtime setup Java scripts Node.js18.x and changed the runtime setup to python 3.9 and HandlerInfo to lambda_function.lambda_handler. I get an error message when I test this function.

Error message"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 4)"

```
import time
import boto3

query = 'SELECT * FROM default.tb'
DATABASE = 'default'
output='s3://AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query = "SELECT * FROM default.tb"
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )
    return response
    return
```

Line 4 is query = 'SELECT * FROM default.tb'

AWS reference file is here
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/schedule-query-athena/

Why do I get this error message?
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you remove that line, do you get the same error a few lines down when you redeclare the variable in the first line of the handler function?

Comment: Also, why do you have two `return` statements?

Comment: There's no apparent syntax error here. The only thing I can think of is that you somehow entered an unprintable, non-whitespace character at the end of line 4.

Comment: Hi Mark B, The code is from aws sample code. I get the same error when I remove the return. I also get the same error message when I comment the line 4 (# query ="SELECT * FROM default.tb")

Comment: Hi chepner, I verify there is not unprintable, non-whitespace character at the end of line 4

Comment: I copy/pasted the code from that [AWS page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/schedule-query-athena/) into a Python 3.9 Lambda function and it's syntactically valid and runs as expected.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Do you create the lambda function with runtime setup Java scripts Node.js18.x and changed the runtime setup to python 3.9 and HandlerInfo to lambda_function.lambda_handler? The code is good if I create lambda function with runtime setup python 3.9

Comment: Originally, I did not go the Node.js 18 to Python 3.9 route but I just tested that and it worked correctly too. I had to rename the handler function from index.handler to lambda_function.lambda_handler but other than that it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, It works when I remove '' inside my query. query = 'SELECT * FROM default.tb where date='2022-12-10' limit 5'  invalid syntax
    query = 'SELECT * FROM default.tb where date=2022-12-10 limit 5' It is good

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that your code is actually `query = 'SELECT * FROM default.tb where date='2022-12-10' limit 5'` (not as shown above). Is that right? That's a syntax error because of the single quotes within single quotes, of course.

Comment: So, mix up your quotes e.g. `query = "SELECT * FROM default.tb where date='2022-12-10' limit 5"`